# Blazor Webassembly - JWT in headers (before my app)

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

How can I use a JWT which is issued upstream of my application (Webassembly hosted by ASP.NET Core)?

1. The customer clicks on the URL [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
2. An external provider takes care of the authentication (before my Blazor app - Webassembly hosted by ASP.NET Core)
3. The external provider redirects the user to [www.example.com/myblazorapp](http://www.example.com/myblazorapp) with the JWT in the headers
4. "MyBlazorApp" must retrieve this JWT and use it during future calls to APIs